# How to avoid python argv refer to file in the system

Tags: python, linux

I tried to do some work that need to deal with python's argv in linux.

The command called shall be something like python test.py export file xxx.json, and I could use argv[4] as file_name. And here if I just write * as file_name, it would be the first file in the current directory.

How can I avoid this kind of error? argv[4] == '*' will return false.

Comment: `*` as a filename is always a bad idea, since it will be expanded by a shell to match all files in the current directories (and directory names as well); in arbitrary order. So "first file" is not well defined anyway.

Comment: Use a proper argument handler. Python has `argparse` built-in, you could start with that. Then you can make the third argument purely optional, and set it to a specific file if it's not given.

Comment: Use a quote "*"

Comment: The expansion of `*` is a shell feature and the full list of files is handled over to the Python program already. There's nothing Python can do about this. You have to find a solution on shell level.

Comment: * is not what I want to enter before, it is something I want to prevent user write here.  And maybe I need to modify the place where call this script

Answer (score 2):

Quote the asterisk when starting your program:

```
python test.py export file "*"
```

Btw, it is not python that is extending the asterisk but it is your shell when you call the program. The python program will get in its argv list all files in your current directory.

As others commented, expecting a literal "*" as argument for your programs is bad practice, better to use a flag. Check the `argparse` module how to make proper command line interfaces.